# Is it possible to inject the server generated Firebase AppCheck debug token into the android app?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-app-check

The Flutter Firebase AppCheck debug token generated on the device gets removed on uninstall. It's tedious to have to keep adding a new token to the server.

The server provides the option to generate a token, so there must be a way to inject it into the application.

I don't see anything in the documentation though.